# Wildfly 10 Clustering does not work when a project's new release deployed with Infinispan Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, wildfly, infinispan, wildfly-10

I have a cluster environment on AWS with Wildfly 10. It consists of two nodes. When 2 exactly same war in two nodes, environment works perfect. But when some changes happens on a project I want to shutdown one of the nodes and try to deploy new version. After that I want to change the other node content. But I get the following error;

```
15:37:51,190 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder$1.run(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:107)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:172)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:870)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:639)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:628)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:531)
        at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:222)
        at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:849)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:621)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:572)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:440)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.lambda$getCache$6(DefaultCacheContainer.java:119)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:114)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.CacheBuilder.start(CacheBuilder.java:80)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder$1.run(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:102)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete(StateTransferManagerImpl.java:224)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)
        ... 18 more

15:37:51,253 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,261 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("component" => "backup-for")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,262 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("component" => "backups")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,264 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("component" => "eviction")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,268 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("component" => "expiration")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,269 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("component" => "locking")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,270 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("component" => "partition-handling")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,270 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("component" => "state-transfer")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
15:37:51,271 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
    ("cache-container" => "aero"),
    ("replicated-cache" => "default"),
    ("store" => "none")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.aero.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.aero.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache default on node1"}}
```

My infinispan cache definition on standalone-ha.xml is;

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">  
  <cache-container name="aero" default-cache="default">  
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>  
    <replicated-cache name="default" mode="SYNC">  
      <transaction mode="BATCH"/>  
    </replicated-cache>  
  </cache-container>  
...
```

And my cache definition on Java is;

```
public class ApplicationCache {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/aero/default")
    private Cache<String, String> cache; 

    .....
}
```

What is my problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT** My jgroups configuration;

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:4.0">
<channels default="ee">
    <channel name="ee" stack="s3ping"/>
<channels>
<stacks>          
    <stack name="s3ping">
       <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp" diagnostics-socket-binding="jgroups-diagnostics"/>
           <protocol type="S3_PING">
               <property name="access_key">
                   <%= @s3_access_key %>
               </property>
               <property name="secret_access_key">
                   <%= @s3_secret_access_key %>
               </property>
               <property name="prefix">
                   <%= @s3_bucket %>
               </property>
               <property name="timeout">
                   60000
               </property>
           </protocol>
           <protocol type="MERGE2"/>
           <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>              
           <protocol type="FD"/>
           <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
           <protocol type="BARRIER"/>
           <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
           <protocol type="UNICAST2"/>
           <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
           <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
           <protocol type="UFC"/>
           <protocol type="MFC"/>
           <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
       </stack>
</stacks>
</subsystem>
```

**EDIT 2** Other nodes stack trace;

[image: Node 2 stack trace]

I had to add this as image because SO limits me about chracter size.

Comment: Could you please post your JGroups configuration? My lucky guess is that you use a discovery protocol (like TCPPING) with static list of nodes whereas you should use some dynamic discovery protocol (like MPING).

Comment: I am using s3ping. A shared the necessary part.

Comment: What does the logs from the other node show?

Comment: I have added other node's stack trace

Comment: Does your web application include new classes which are serialized within the session? To me it seems that the cache i can't be synchronized if you start the changed node. Maybe there is a class you removed in the session or the new war create a new session with classes which are not provided by the old one. Interesting might be if you check whether the same procedure works everytime correct with to identical war's (not sure whether you test that several times with existing sessions). Also you can show what the changes of the war are (or reduce it for a test)

Comment: there is no change in classes stored in caches. I am sure about it. Also, if wars become identical, it works without any problem. I also tried that I remove my cache and deploy two different version of an application. At this situation session replication does not work also.

Answer (score 0):

WildFly creates a module for every deployment.  In order for the new version of your application to be considered the same module as the previous version, you need to ensure that the runtime name of the deployment does not include a version number - as this is used to generate the module name for the deployment.
There are 2 ways to do this:
1. Just remove the version from your archive name - this will allow you to use the file scanner based deployment without issue.
2. Deploy your application via the console/CLI, and specify a consistent runtime name.  See: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Application+deployment

Care must be taken to preserve serialized form of your cached objects between deployment versions.  If serialized form cannot be preserved, you should create an isolated cluster to use with the new deployment version such that the data in the distributed cache stays segregated.

Comment: I tried first way before and it did not work. I will try second way. I hope it helps

Comment: I wonder what is the difference of way 2 from running standalone.sh.